# Set attributes for multiple elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have table:

```
<table class="checkout-list">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th class="checkout-title">item</th>
         <th class="checkout-title">amount</th>
         <th class="checkout-title">total</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td class="checkout-info"></td>
        <td class="checkout-info"></td>
        <td class="checkout-info"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="checkout-info"></td>
          <td class="checkout-info"></td>
          <td class="checkout-info"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

And with javascript I want to take values from `thead tr th` and set them to `tbody tr td` as attributes.
I tried this:

```
let title = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-title').forEach(el => {
      title.push(el.innerHTML);
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-info').forEach((el, index) => {
      el.setAttribute('data-title', title[index]);
   });
```

Bus as it is now I only manage to assign values to first `tbody tr td` child and second left with undefined it looks like this:

```
<tbody>
       <tr>
        <td class="checkout-info" data-title="item"></td>
        <td class="checkout-info" data-title="amount"></td>
        <td class="checkout-info" data-title="total"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="checkout-info" data-title="undefined"></td>
          <td class="checkout-info" data-title="undefined"></td>
          <td class="checkout-info" data-title="undefined"></td>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

How I should fix this undefined assignation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the code is, there are only three nodes with `querySelector` `document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-title')`  and six nodes with `querySelector` `document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-info')`. That's why there is value for first 3 nodes and `undefined` for last three nodes.

You have to access nodes from `title` array with `title[index % header.length]` so that it will loop through the title twice and assign the attribute correctly

```js
let title = [];
const header = document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-title');
header.forEach(el => {
  title.push(el.innerHTML);
});

const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-info');
nodes.forEach((el, index) => {
  el.setAttribute('data-title', title[index % header.length]);
});
```

```html
<table class="checkout-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="checkout-title">item</th>
      <th class="checkout-title">amount</th>
      <th class="checkout-title">total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="checkout-info"></td>
      <td class="checkout-info"></td>
      <td class="checkout-info"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="delivery_price">
      <td class="checkout-info"></td>
      <td class="checkout-info"></td>
      <td class="checkout-info"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nice!  solution
but because  the table has  3 column  its works fine with % operator (its always return  0 to 2 ) but if you add one more column then code won't work

Comment: @CyC0der As per the question the colum count for the header and body are same. If they are not same, then there should be some logic how the attributes are to be splitted.